# Sending 'STOP' SMS to recepients from Twilio number

Tags: mobile, sms, twilio, blacklist

I'm not sure why it wouldn't, but I haven't seen this question asked: Is it possible to basically blacklist numbers that send SMS to a Twilio number by sending 'STOP' to their number from the Twilio number? I know the reverse is possible: https://www.twilio.com/help/faq/sms/does-twilio-support-stop-block-and-cancel-aka-sms-filtering. I ask because Twilio does not have the ability to block SMS from specific numbers.

Answer (score 2):

At this time, as far as I am aware you can't blacklist numbers to prevent them from sending SMS messages to your Twilio number. Which is unfortunate because this does allow someone to perfrom a DoS attack (or at least run up your twilio bill) by endlessly texting your twilio number.

In order to stop an sms message sent from a phone to your twilio number the message would have to get to the [twilio] number in order for you/twilio to know if it should be blocked. Also phone numbers can be spoofed so blocking by number could be problematic if the person harassing your twilio number is intent on pestering you.

From my understanding, sending 'stop' to a number to tell the "number owner" to stop sending messages to your twilio number is implemented at a higher (software) layer.

Here is what twilio has to say about this: https://www.twilio.com/help/faq/sms/is-there-a-way-to-block-incoming-sms-on-my-twilio-phone-number

Comment: Why would SMS STOP filtering be unsupported in the other direction?

Comment: Twilio developer evangelist here. Justin is right in that STOP messages are implemented by the number owner. It's something we provide for our numbers, but is not necessarily implemented elsewhere. @Riftus if you are having problems with incoming spam or abuse on your number, please do get in touch with Twilio support on help@twilio.com and we will work with you to sort it out.

Comment: At risk of angering the Twilio gods - there are other SMS providers that don't charge for inbound SMS, so in that case just drop messages from numbers you want to block (cloud/server bill would still get hit in case of DoS/abuse/etc.)